# prestashop create and update resources via url webservice api

Tags: php, web-services, rest, prestashop

I (unfortunately) have to write a client application as front end to a prestashop powered web site. I'd need to perform all CRUD operations on resources via url webservice and I'm stuck on create and update. I was very surprise to find out how few examples are available on the web since prestashop is supposed to be a widely used cms. However, till now I came to:

```
GET http://www.myshop.com/api/myresource/id
```

to get xml for resource with given id or

```
GET http://www.myshop.com/api/myresource/?display=full&filter[field]=[value]
```

to filter results. I'm writing this just because I had to struggle with google to achieve this information, this filters stuff might help somebody in the future.

```
DELETE http://www.myshop.com/api/myresource/id
```

to delete a resource (I suppose filters work here too, but didn't try so far)

now, does somebody know how create and update resources? I tried

```
POST/PUT http://www.myshop.com/api/myresource/
```

giving couples of field - value in http request parameters with no luck, I'm getting internal server error. No, I have no direct access to the server so I don't know what error is thrown and I hope it can be solved without bother website maintainers, I'd like to save my ammunitions.

The only useful resource I found on the web is [this one](http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/720902/CRUD%20Tutorial%20EN.pdf), I also looked among other question on SO and suggested links in those question was of no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit your config/config.inc.php and add the following you will be able to see the errors in the Response (error) (1by1 which is very frustrating when you are trying to work out why create fails). Remember to comment out the line when you are done.

```
/*DEBUGGING ON*/
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

You also need to make sure that you prepend the data in your POST/PUT operation with **xml=**`<prestashop>......</prestashop>` (I am using C# for my Client so this may not be required with PHP)

if you are using the `?schema=synopsis` to get your blank one, make sure you go through any elements in the XML that are in there as placeholders and remove them.. Your (products) for example will be broken but kind of work if you don't.

I also added to my code that in the initial pass of the XML it completely walks the tree, looking for anything with the attribute `not_filterable` and removes those nodes (once again not much documentation available to know if this is the right thing to do).

EDIT: 1 other thing of note in and of the Language based elements, make sure you are using CDATA for the elements.

I have just succeeded with Generating my Products via performing this so I hope it's of help. I am yet to perform an Update of an existing.

UPDATE: I have since updated to 1.5.4.1 of Prestashop and started updating resource Products in my case

**Update Resource**

URI: `http://site/api/products/1`

Use Method = `"PUT"`

content type = `"text/xml"`

Make sure that you remove any elements that have 'not_filterable' attribute set. (I don't understand why, but it doesn't work if you don't)

**Delete Resource**

URI: `http://site/api/products/1`

Use Method = `"DELETE"`

content type = `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

I found that you don't need any body so you can set ContentLength to 0 it seems. and probaly don't really need content type to be set either, but it works.

Comment: thanks for the details! I have no access to the server so I'm not going to see any error but I already made a try (java-android) and it seems to work, please edit your answer with the url so I can accept it ^^

Comment: oh, another thing, why should I use CDATA? I made tried without and it worked, am I going to get some problem sooner or later?

Comment: Which URL do you require?  The cdata is I just noticed before I left the office today it eroded when I had an & in the product name as when I put that into a regular xmlelement it gets encoded and causes the we service to error 500.

Comment: Encoded the & to &amp; ( as XML should). Sorry for the 2nd comment couldn't edit on my phone.

Comment: ok thanks, don't worry about the url, I meant the one I wrote in my answer but I'm not going to delete it

Comment: hey, sorry to bother you again but I'm stuck on prestashop's api...again. I'm trying to update an address calling a put on http://mysite.com/api/addresses/322 and then setting xml=<prestashop>...etc as parameter. Server responds with 4 (!) errors...do you have any idea what could be wrong? I tried every sort of combination for the xml (removing all fields but the one I want to update, sending them all, just a few etc...) but nothing works...!!

Comment: I think I recall in my application when posting PUT you don't include the XML = stuff... and set the content type to text/xml (of the correct derivation of that)

Comment: @PaulFarry, Mr. Paul, While searching for a working code snippet to update an entity in Prestashop I came accros this old question. I would very much appreciate it if you would help me with this. I followed your intructions and it didn't work, made several variations on the request and still didn't work...I am very frustrated about how bad this is documented...a simple working C#/F# code would be very helpful. Looking forward to hearing to answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in source code, prestashop/webservice/dispatcher.php, there was no need to set fields/values as http parameters but rather pass a whole xml, containing at least all required fields, if using a post to create a new record, or just the fields you want to be updated if requesting a put, so

```
http://www.myshop.com/api/myresource/?xml=myXmlString
```

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the documentation, you can ask for a blank `xml` file with all fields the each ressource. You have to do :

```
http://mystore.com/api/[resource name]?schema=blank
```

Then if you need more informations about the fields (as some are mandatory), just do :

```
http://mystore.com/api/[resource name]?schema=synopsis
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but I don't understand what this has to do with my question...

Comment: As it's told in the documentation, you have to construct an xml file and send it this way : `$opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);`

Comment: as it's told in the question, I need to access resources via url and I have no access to server, so, what am I suppose to do with php code?

Comment: if I didn't explain clearly what is my problem, please tell me what part is not clear, if you are just answering randomly, please give up

Comment: You have to use the `POST` method `http://mystore.com/api/[resource name]` and the needed ressource's fields. In which langage are you coding your client application ?